# swap the first two lines in all files in a folder

Tags: bash, awk, swap

I want to swap the first two lines in all files in a folder and save that over the existing files, keeping file names as before.

What I have:

```
awk '{getline x;print x}1' *.map.txt
```

Can this be written only for the first two lines?

What this does is just print in the terminal all the outputs for each file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with sed :

```
sed '1{h;d};2{x;H;x}'
```

Explanation :

```
1 and 2 are line number selectors ; the following commands will only be executed on those lines
h puts the current line in the 'hold' buffer
d deletes the line
x swaps the hold buffer with the current line
H appends the current line to the hold buffer
```

Test run with GNU sed :

> ```
> $ mkdir test35597922
> $ echo """line1
> > line2
> > line3""" > test35597922/file1.txt
> $ echo """line1
> line2
> line3""" > test35597922/file2.txt
> $ sed -i '1{h;d};2{x;H;x}' test35597922/*
> $ ls test35597922/
> file1.txt  file2.txt
> $ cat test35597922/file1.txt
> line2
> line1
> line3
> $ cat test35597922/file2.txt
> line2
> line1
> line3
> ```

If you can't use the 'in place' `-i` flag and want to edit the files, you can process as follows :

```
for file in test35597922/*; do
  sed '1{h;d};2{x;H;x}' $file > tmp_file
  mv tmp_file $file
done
```

On some systems it could be done in one action (`sed '1{h;d};2{x;H;x}' $file > $file`) but that will fail on others, the file being overwriten before it has entirely been read.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make this overwrite each file in the folder maintaining each name as before?

Comment: use sed's `-i` flag. according to posix you're supposed to suffix it with a backup extention, i.e. `-i.bak` which will be used to create backup files, but in bash (at least) you can omit it if you don't want backup files

Comment: Sorry, but can't seem to work it out. Couldn't that be handled in another way?
I just need to save each file in the folder after sed does its job...

Comment: I've added a test run, I hope that clears any confusion

Comment: `-i` is _not_ specified by POSIX… POSIX only specifies `-e`, `-f` and `-n`. See the [POSIX `sed` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116).

Comment: Isn't working but I think because of the folder hierarchy. How do I include the specification for the directory? I tried:                                                   sed -e '1{N;s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/;}' /home/andre/Desktop/PRJEB0000/mapping_files/*.map.txt

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thanks, I had been told `-i<suffix>` was POSIX specified, glad that mistake was cleared. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: @AndréSoares you're using sat's answer here, and without the `-i` flag, so it will only output the edited stream, without saving it. I'm in the process of editing my answer to specify how to edit the files without the `-i` flag if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

With `ed` (and Bash):

```
for file in ./*; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue
    ed -s "$file" <<< $'1m2\nw\nq\n'
done
```

The `ed` command that does the trick is: `1m2` that selects the first line and moves it to the 2nd line. If you have files with 0 or 1 lines, you'll see some harmless `?` on standard error. You can redirect them to `/dev/null` by appending `2> /dev/null` after the `done`.

Answer (score 0):

Another `sed`:

```
sed -e '1{N;s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/;}' file
```

Use `-i` to affect the changes in file.

If you don't have `-i` option, try below way.

```
sed -e '1{N;s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/;}' file > new_file && mv new_file file
```

Comment: Operating in a large amount of files, how can I make new_file names correspond to file?

Comment: @AndréSoares, You can use like this : `for file in *.map.txt; do sed -e '1{N;s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/;}' "$file" > new_file && mv new_file "$file" ; done`. This will process the files one by one.